# Поиск в массиве используя регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как организовать поиск в массиве используя регулярные выражения? К примеру вот код:

```
var arr = ['земля', 'вода', 'воздух', 'огонь'];
$('input').keyup(function(){
var val = $('input').val();
var re = new RegExp(val, 'i');
var result = arr.match(re);
return result.input;
});
```

Как сделать, чтобы при вводе допустим 'огонь', он возвратил 'огонь'?

Comment: "он возвратил 'огонь'" - куда возвратил?

Comment: ну возвратить я могу куда угодно, мне нужно чтобы в 'result.input' было то, что вводит пользователь, но поиск в массиве

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = ['земля', 'вода', 'воздух', 'огонь'];
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var val = $('input').val().toLowerCase();
  var result = arr.filter(item => item.startsWith(val));
  console.log(result);
  if (result.length) {
    // return result или val куда надо
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="ОГонь" />
```

Comment: На сколько понимаю, в инпут может прийти не только одно слово, по этому надо в регулярку значение массива класть, и тестить вал, а не наоборот.

Comment: а возможно ли чтобы он возвращал строку целиком, к пример начал вводить 'огонь' а в нем уже 'огонь'? val.input не работает

Comment: @SaulGoodman Что же Вы так косноязычно выражаетесь? Вам надо находить в массиве строку, которая начинается со строки, которая введена в инпут? (`val` это строка. У нее нет свойства `input`.)

Comment: Да все верно мне нужно найти строку в массиве, которая начинается со строки,которая введена в инпуте, а по поводу свойства input я про регулярку, когда ищешь методом match() то в результате добавляешь .input чтобы он выводил полностью строку к примеру var a = 'java'; var result = a.match(/j/i); alert(result.input) // java а если input не добавлять то выведет // j

Comment: @SaulGoodman что должно находится, когда в инпут введено "во"?

Comment: должно находится: вода, воздух